# How to uploading video on azure cloud and can I place matlab exe on cloud?

Tags: matlab, azure

I want to ask about azure cloud services. How can we upload a video to azure cloud.  Can we place a matlab project exe on cloud (it is for computation)?  If anybody has a video tutorial regarding my question, kindly send a video link as well. I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at [this documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-content/) ?

Comment: yes i have seen the document.it gives infromation about how to upload and encrypt the video on cloud but i also asked that can we place exe files of matlab on cloud?

Comment: Did that answer your first question, though?

Answer (score 0):

For the answer to your first question, see [Microsoft's media documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-content/).

For the answer to your second question, it looks like you can place matlab files on azure.  From [Microsoft Azure](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/azure/faq.aspx):

**Can I run Matlab on Azure?**

Matlab can be used to “compile” a Matlab application and it is possible to upload this compiled code and libraries to Windows Azure.
We have not yet installed a complete Matlab instance on Windows Azure, but it is a project currently under study.